# Get thumbnail from sd card match it to its file

Tags: java, android

Am building a file manager to use with my app,  I need to able to get the thumbnails of the image files and all the videos. That's only possible if this questions are true:

1. Does android keep thumbnails of all images & videos in something like a database where it can be queried and match to the respective files?
2. If thats true,  how can I get a thumbnail and match it to its file e.g an image?

NOTE: Please don't show me how to get a thumbnail from a media file,  that's not what am asking.

Comment: As far as I know Android does not store thumbnails centrally, you have to create and store them yourself.

Comment: Ok...I guess Al have to create my own